# Linear search in c#

Tags: c#, linear-search

Hey guys I am a beginner at coding and I'm doing a linear search in c# and can't figure out how to make it show in what array the number was found when doing the search. It just makes it say that it's on the last array. Here's my code:

```
Random Generator = new Random();
int[] array = new int[100];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = Generator.Next(1, 100);
    count++;
}
Console.WriteLine("Write a number between 1-100 and see if it's in a array and in what array.");
int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

bool exists = array.Contains(guess);
if (exists)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} is in the {1}th Array.", guess, count);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} does not match any number in any of the Arrays.", guess);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

There's something wrong with my count int, but I don't know what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by _something wrong_ exactly? Unexpected result? What result do you want it instead? Please read [ask] couple of times.

Comment: Your text does not match your code at all. You have *one* array. All your output text implies you want to have multiple arrays.

Comment: @nvoigt  arrays == array-elements

Comment: @snoodel : You are not actually doing a linear search yourself here, just calling the Contains() method. As an exercise that's a little small.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is if a number between 1-99 is found in one of the arrays then make the program tell which of the arrays it was found in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Array.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Int index = Array.IndexOf(amountOfArrays,guess);
If (index == -1)
{
    // not found
}
else 
{
    // found
}
```

Count++ will be the last.  How would you expect it to be anything else?

Comment: Likely interpretation of the question, but where does the name `amountOfArrays` come from? The asker uses the identifier `array`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It is just a variable name.  It is clearly used as array size.   I suspect English is not the OP's native language.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I'm pretty clueless as towards where I should use that? You mean instead of array.Contains?

Comment: Array.IndexOf will give you the position.  Use that rather than count.

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to System.Array error

Comment: Then you are not using what I posted.  Sorry but I am not going to continue to try and help you.  You have shown minimal effort.

Comment: Thanks anyways, I'm gonna keep trying. I will get this working.

Comment: I got it!            `if(index == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} does not match any number in any of the Arrays.", guess);
            }
            else 
            {
                count+= index;
                Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} is in the {1}th Array.", guess, count);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();`